# Lock access to XML file located on shared drive from user, but not from program

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am developing a program that, in part, will store user credentials in the following format:

```
<root>
 <Testing_Files>
  <file docNum="7132" type="acct"/>
  <file docNum="5243" type="bags"/>
  <file docNum="7567" type="parse"/>
 </Testing_Files>
 <Accounts>
  <user name="Jon" email="XXX@XXX.com" password="****" phone="555-555-5555" ext="104"/>
  <user name="Joey" email="XXX@XXX.com" password="******" phone="555-555-5555" ext="134"/>
  <user name="Tim" email="XXX@XXX.com" password="******" phone="555-555-5555" ext="123"/>
 </Accounts>
</root>
```

I have this file saved to a local server with a domain of "da". I need to find a way of allowing access to the application, but not to the user. This file will contain sensitive information including passwords and other sensitive data.

I have tried a couple of solutions including trying to use something along the lines of an Impersonator, however every snippet of code I can find behind one of these Impersonators calls for elevated privileges that I do not want normal users getting their hands on.

```
<edit>
 The reason that I am trying to use an Impersonator is because on the server 
side I have an account set up with a password called "GENERATOR" that only 
has access to a couple of files like this, so I have been trying to grant 
the application access with these credentials.
<edit reason="I have the dumb"/>
</edit>
```

I have thought of possibly encrypting the XML file while not in use, and decrypting a copy on the client side, just to get this portion working. We require this portion of code to be completed before I can move onto the next part, and I am beginning to think of just doing it a simpler less secure way.

Any help or feedback is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: at least the password should be encrypted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is the encrypt the file or use a service to secure the data and/or file. There is not a simple solution for this.